# RHEL specific version images not available in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, boot, disk-image

When trying to create VM instances in GCP compute Engine, only RHEL latest versions images are available for each release.
RHEL 7.9 and RHEL 8.3 are available. But unable to find RHEL 7.6/7.7/7.8/8.1/8.2 images in the Marketplace and Public images. Refer to this image.
[RHEL 7 gives RHEL 7.9 and RHEL 8 gives RHEL 8.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk4lv.png) How can I get the lower versions of RHEL without SAP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. Only the latest supported version of RHEL is provided on Google Cloud.

There is generally no good reason to do this anyway, not even the word of your third party software vendor. But if you really want to go to all the trouble, you certainly can.

In order to run out of date versions of RHEL you would need to:

1. Purchase RHEL and [Extended Update Support](https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-eus) subscriptions for the old version you want to run directly from Red Hat.
2. Create your own OS images of that RHEL version which include those subscriptions and upload them to Google Cloud. With your active RHEL subscription you can download cloud OS images from Red Hat that you can use directly.

Note that the costs of doing this are significantly higher than the costs of simply running the provided latest RHEL images.